# span overlay: click will be triggered in IE when  it shouldn't

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following code. When you click the button, a click handler on the span overlay is triggered which then disables the button. Effectively toggling the button state. In Chrome and FireFox, this works, the button is disabled, clicking on it does not trigger click handler on the span overlay. However, in IE, the button is disabled but you can click on it and it will trigger the click handler on the span overlay.

Is there a way to fix this while keeping a similar form? I can't remove the handler on the span overlay since I can't find a way to reattach it when needed (the overlay/button is generated dynamically) and I need the overlay for the extra id parameter. Any ideas?

```
    <span id="id_1" style="display:inline-block">
       <button id="id_2">Click Me</button>
    </span>
```

Comment: A rule I always set for myself is that if code works in IE and nothing else... then you should probably rewrite that code altogether rather than search for a patch for modern browsers.

Comment: @cereallarceny: appears as if it works everywhere except in IE

Comment: You haven't provided any CSS with this! Is the overlay tranparent or does it contain colour? IE treats empty elements as if they do not exist so you will be able to interact with the content below.

Comment: @Dr.Molle: then the question should be reworded, it suggests that the code is working in IE only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check the disabled-property of the button before you run the code:

```
$('#id_1')
 .click(function(e)
        {
         if(e.target.disabled){return;}
         /* code to execute when button is enabled*/
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

One little question, the inline styling is also being generated?

Maybe you can try to style the span with a z-index of 1 and the button with an absolute position and give it a z-index of 10 (or more).